# The underlying library FreeCAD uses to manipulate STEP file format and format conversion

Tags: cad

I am looking for answers to the following questions concerning FreeCAD from someone who is familiar with implementation of FreeCAD :

1. Which library FreeCAD uses to parse STEP file format?
2. Which library FreeCAD uses to convert file of STEP format to Obj format?
3. Is it possible (or how hard is it) to use the above mentioned libraries as standalone libraries in other projects. I have checked some options, but they are all proprietary software.
4. If one has many files of STEP format that need to be converted to Obj format, is it possible to write a script to call FreeCAD to do it in a batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open Cascade.
2. Open Cascade provides triangulation. Parsing step is pretty easy, hell the  standard documents  a parser. But having a triangulation and underlying  data manipulation package makes the difference.  This is why its  called a CAD kernel.
3. Yes. Its nontrivial to use cascade directly. That said it does include examples.
4. Yes.